# How to drop RST packets?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, firewall, ipsec

Is it possible to filter all outgoing TCP packets with RST flag on Windows Server 2003 using IPSec utility from "Support tools"?

Article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813878

Comment: One word: Why?!?

Comment: @EEAA In some anycast/load balancing scenarios the ability to selectively drop RST packets can be convenient. But I don't think that's what this question is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using IPSec, you cannot specify a combination of TCP flags to filter.